# How to use UWB sensor for localization instead of nav2_amcl?

Tags: navigation, ros2

My project application scenario is in a large warehouse.
I do not have any Lidar devices, and I don't want to use any Lidars (Because the expensive price). But I have a few of UWB sensors (including tags and receivers).

I want to use navigation2 package in ros2 galactic.
I already have odometry with wheel encode and imu. And the 2D map also has been ready.

I can receive inital pose of robot from uwb sensors, but I don't know how to send it to bt_navigator without nav2_amcl.

Can anyone help me? I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

AMCL only provides the Map->Odom transform at the core of its value to Nav2. So, as long as your UWB solution provides that TF transform, then you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/linorobot/ros_dwm1000

Check out this repo! Also this one:

https://github.com/cliansang/uwb-tracking-ros